# How much weight will this structure hold?

Tags: woodworking, lumber

I'm going to build this structure as is.  This question is not the same as [my earlier post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/176043/how-much-weight-can-a-2-by-4-support-in-this-configuration) as I am not seeking any more design advice as in the previous.

I will not make any more changes to it.

My question is "How much weight will it hold".  The goal is to put a bed on top of it that will support a 200 lb man.

Please no more design ideas.  I just want to know how much weight it will support.

50lbs? , 100lbs?, 200lbs?

Thanks.

It will be completely built with 2" by 6" by 8' whitewood dimensional lumber from Home Depot and one piece of standard 1/2" plywood.

The casters are rated for about 250 lbs each and placed at the 4 corners shaded black.

Quantitatively, what is an estimate of how much this will hold?

[image]

Comment: I built bunk beds of about those dimensions and the 1/2 plywood held over 300 pounds ( two people) by itself . The plywood was supported only on the perimeter by 1 " angle iron.

Comment: Do you remember the width of the span on the bunk bed by chance?

Comment: **We can not answer that for you**. If you are going to build it "regardless of the weight it will hold" then build it and put weight on it until it fails and then you will know the answer.

Comment: Turn the 2x 's so they are not flat, put plywood on both sides. strong.

Comment: I'm voting to close because the goal of the question is to refine a design fairly precisely, and that is well beyond what you can possibly expect from any internet forum; OP needs a structural engineer.

Comment: OP is an engineer in a different field and can discern the best answer from best guesses.  It is called continuous improvement and taught in TQM classes.

Comment: The next design iteration will use aluminum and please don't vote to close that one b.c. it is similar to this one.  It has a better weight to strength ratio and that is one reason it is used in planes that ... fly.

Comment: OP needs to understand how stack exchange works, *Answers are for questions that can be answered, not  "best guess's"* **Ask a question that can be answered, do not post a series of design changes so you can refine your plan**.

Comment: the weakest parts look to be the footings so that should support a 200 pound man,

Comment: take an 8 foot 2x6 ... lay it flat on the ground ... insert a block under each end ... stand on the middle ... observe the deflection ... extrapolate the deflection of the finished product

Comment: If you are an engineer, there are beam equations and calculators online. Using https://www.engineersedge.com/beam_bending/beam_bending3.htm , for one flat 2x6, 7 ft long, 200 lbs in the middle, it will deflect 1.2 inches. I will post the calculation on the other question.

Comment: the wood will hold the 1000lbs the casters handle, unless you REALLY botch something putting it together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question leaves too many unknown factors for an estimate, even using lumber loading tables. Some that come to mind:

- Load concentration: If most of the weight is transferred through to the casters, it'll carry whatever the casters tolerate. If the load is *mushy*, the failure point would be at the center of the span.
- Dynamic forces due to movement: Will you be rolling the thing around under load? What sort of surface will this be on? Impact forces from bumps greatly reduce load limits.
- Lumber selection: Wood species, grain quality, and integral flaws (knots, pitch pockets) could all lead to failure at a weak point.
- Build quality: Your carpentry plays a role, as does the type and number of fasteners used.

It'll carry at least a few hundred pounds if built fairly well. Asking for a true load rating isn't reasonable, though.

Comment: Good answer.  Will not move under load.  Dynamic load only comes from the person.  This is dimensional whitewood from Home Depot picked by hand.  Will use either wood screws or bolts with washers to connect it all.  Probably bolts as I can replace parts if needed.